# Help me with this GRE question

Tags: homework, gre

Human nature and long distances have made exceeding the speed limit a (i)__ in the state, so the legislators surprised no one when, acceding to public demand, they (ii)__ increased penalties for speeding.

> (i)
>   A. controversial habit
>   B. cherished tradition
>   C. disquieting ritual
>
> (ii)
>   D. endorsed
>   E. considered
>   F. rejected

The correct answer are B & F. But I just wonder what is wrong if I select A & D? I think the sentence still makes sense and correct grammatically.

Comment: Magoosh's answer- https://youtu.be/S4as7cfUG7Y?si=-6s3FxJztS9Q8Br6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One problem with

> *Human nature and long distances have made exceeding the speed limit a controversial habit in the state, so the legislators surprised no one when, acceding to public demand, they endorsed increased penalties for speeding*

is that it is not clear how *human nature and long distances* could be at the root of a controversial habit.  Long distances might make speeding a habit, but what makes it controversial?  Neither of those two factors seem to make for controversy.

Another problem is that having the legislators endorse greater penalties would not be a natural expectation caused by the controversial habit.  If there was controversy over whether speeding was a problem or not, there would not be clear public demand for the legislators to accede to, and it would not be a foregone conclusion that the politicians would endorse higher penalties for it.

Comment: I think the key is really in the phrase "surprised no one" and agree with you and pageman on that point. For the first part of your explanation I do not agree - human nature and long distances can make exceeding the speed limit a controversial habit in the same manner as they can make it a cherished tradition: by assuming that it is in human nature to break speed limits (esp. over long distances) you will definitively have a controversy on your hands (legislation vs human nature). It is actually the cherished tradition that is harder to establish. However, it does make more sense overall.

Comment: It seems strange to connect 'speeding' and 'tradition'. Everything else is OK (about the GRE question/answer and your explanation).

Comment: I think it could be considered a controversial habbit because although due to long distances people are doing it, it is not something liked by everyone- maybe it has increased accidents. Therefore although there would be a group of people opposing penalties- the ones overspending, there will be another group supporting penalties-the ones who have to bear losses due to overspeeding, and maybe over time the latter group has become more numerous hence public demand refers to them

Answer (score 3):

It would make sense grammatically but it wouldn't make sense when you consider causality — as mgkrebbs pointed out; the legislation should be a function of public demand — choosing A would make the causal choice of D ambiguous (and therefore the qualifier "surprised no one" wouldn't make any sense).

Answer (score 0):

Human nature and long distances have made exceeding the speed limit a (i)__ in the state, so the legislators surprised no one when, acceding to public demand, they (ii)__ increased penalties for speeding.

For first blank some thing should come which is liked by public, 
out of:-
A. controversial habit
B. cherished tradition
C. disquieting ritual

B seems the best choice

For the second blank, adhering to public demand some step is taken, now its a cherished tradition to exceed the speed limit, then public demands will be to decrease/remove(a negative word) the penalities

D. endorsed
E. considered
F. rejected

only F is a negative word, B & F is the solution according to me.